# How to add new command to test case

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE Record function to create test cases. 
I would like to take screenshot at some part of application that I am testing.

Using UI of Selenium IDE it is easy:

Command: `captureEntirePageScreenshot`,
Target: `*path for screenshot*`

But it is not convenient to manually type this (or copy paste) every time I want to take a screenshot, so I decided to make a plug-in (a button on the Selenium IDE toolbar) that will add this screenshot command to the testcase, once I click on it.

I created my button, which is visible on the toolbar, but right now it does nothing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="toolbar.css" type="text/css"?>
<overlay id="toolbar_overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <toolbar id="toolbar2">
        <toolbarseparator id="screenshot-separator" insertafter="record-button"/>
        <toolbarbutton id="screenshot-button" insertafter="screenshot-separator" label="Take a screenshot" class="icon" tooltiptext="Take a screenshot" command="*problem_is_here*"/>
    </toolbar>
</overlay>
```

I was digging through Selenium IDE source code, but didn't find method that can be used to add new command to the test case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did more digging through source code and find required method:

`Editor.addCommand(command, target, value, window, insertBeforeLastCommand)`

So my final .xul file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="toolbar.css" type="text/css"?>

<overlay id="toolbar_overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<toolbar id="toolbar2">
    <toolbarseparator id="screenshot-separator" insertafter="record-button"/>
    <toolbarbutton id="screenshot-button" insertafter="screenshot-separator" label="Take a screenshot" class="icon" tooltiptext="Take a screenshot" oncommand="window.editor.addCommand('captureEntirePageScreenshot', 'C:/Users/username/screenshot'+window.FileUtils.getTimeStamp()+'.png', '', window.editor.window);"/>
</toolbar>
</overlay>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look inter user-extensions.js. This is an easy way to add javascript functionality.
To me, it seems silly to reproduce a command that already exists.

With the IDE's autocomplete, I'm not sure why it's complicated to add in this step, unless you want to use it like the right-click menus?